# Best practice for removing parent theme CSS assets etc. without editing parent's functions.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently developing a child theme that builds on twentyfifteen as a parent theme. However a potential issue has cropped up that is causing a problem.

I want to strip the CSS and JS assets from the parent theme twentyfifteen, but these are loaded from the theme's `functions.php` file with `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script`, I have commented out these lines in the `functions.php` file so that now these CSS and JS assets are not longer loaded - but isn't it he case that if an update is released for the twentyfifteen parent theme, that when it is updated - the `functions.php` file will be overwritten along with any commenting out I have done. So in other words when it is updated the unwanted CSS and JS assets will be reloaded.

What is the best solution here? Can I prevent twentyfifteen loading it's stylesheet and JS without editing it's `functions.php` file (as this file will only be updated and changes overwritten?) Surely there is a better way of doing this.

I'm currently developing a child theme for with a base of twentyfifteen and have been left wondering if it would just be best to create an independent theme rather than a child theme as a workaround to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<?php wp_dequeue_style( $handle ) ?>` where `$handle` is the name (slug) of the enqueued stylesheet. Similarly `<?php wp_dequeue_script( $handle ); ?>` for scripts.

See the codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script